# Возможности телеграмбота

Tags: python-3.6, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Возможно ли с помощью телеграм-бота принять фото и переслать его на произвольный email?

Всем спасибо за ответы, вопрос закрыт

Comment: Возможно. Читайте документацию соответствующих python-модулей

Answer (score 2):

Чтоб узнать возможности к примеру telebot вам необходимо найти официальную документацию (желательно на английском,как раз английский потяните) и более подробней изучить.

Answer (score 0):

Да, за ночь пришло озарение. Вопрос делится на две задачи.

1. принять файл.
2. отправить его по email.

Всем спасибо кто ответил.